# Flutter ImagePicker library not invoking aysnc await function?

Tags: flutter, async-await, imagepicker, flutter-image

I have an issue with the ImagePicker library and async-await function. So on my home view, I invoke a function, here is the code

```
onPressed: () {
controller.pickImage();
},
```

Here is my function with ImagePicker

```
  void pickImage() async {
    print("call on click add photo icon");
    final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
    final XFile? pickedImage =
        await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    print(
        'picked image filled with an image from gallery'); //This doesn't print at all

    if (pickedImage != null) {
      Get.snackbar('Profile Picture',
          'You have successfully selected your profile picture!');

      _pickedImage = Rx<File>(File(pickedImage.path));
    }
  }
```

So I tried to debug with this printing, so I get the first print but after that nothing, it looks like I'm losing that await part, I don't know what actually is the problem, it looks await part is never executed.

[image: output of my code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this.

```
Future pickImage() async {
print("call on click add photo icon");
ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
XFile pickedImage =
    await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

print(
    'picked image filled with an image from gallery'); //This doesn't print at all

if (pickedImage != null) {
  Get.snackbar('Profile Picture',
      'You have successfully selected your profile picture!');

  _pickedImage = File(pickedImage.path);
}}
```